# How to provide service inside the component in angular 5 with aot?

Tags: singleton, angular5, angular-aot

I have met the error

> question-images.service.ts(5,2): Error during template compile of
>   'QuestionImagesService'   Only initialized variables and constants can
>   be referenced in decorators because the value of this variable is
>   needed by the template compiler in 'Injectable'
>       'Injectable' references 'Injectable'
>         'Injectable' references 'Injectable'
>           'Injectable' is not initialized at ..\@angular\core\src\di\metadata.ts(138,22)

This is component

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { QuestionImagesService } from '@app/patient/components/assesment/questions/question-images.service';
import { QuestionBase } from '@app/patient/components/assesment/questions/question.base';

@Component({
  selector: 'ez-slider-question',
  templateUrl: './slider-question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider-question.component.scss'],
  providers: [QuestionImagesService]
})
export class SliderQuestionComponent extends QuestionBase implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  minValue: number;
  maxValue: number;
  value: number;
  smallStep: number;
  imageId = 0;
  images: { [key: number]: SafeHtml } = {};

  constructor(private questionImagesService: QuestionImagesService) { super(); }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.minValue = 1;
    this.smallStep = 1;
    this.maxValue = this.question.answers.length;
    this.value = this.question.userAnswers[0]
      ? Number(this.question.answers.find(answer => answer.id === this.question.userAnswers[0].id).value)
      : this.minValue;
    this.images = this.questionImagesService.startLoadingImages(this.question);
  }

  getNewUserAnswerValues(): string[] {
    return [this.value.toString()];
  }

  onValueChange(value: number) {
    this.imageId = this.question.answers.find(answer => answer.value === value.toString()).id;
  }
```

This is service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core/src/core';
import { SafeHtml, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionImagesService {
    private images: { [key: number]: SafeHtml } = {};

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    startLoadingImages(question: IQuestion): { [key: number]: SafeHtml } {
        this.images = {};
        question.answers.forEach(answer => {
            if (answer.imageUrl) {
                this.httpClient.get(`http://localhost:54531/${answer.imageUrl}`, { responseType: 'text' })
                    .subscribe(imageHtml => this.images[answer.id] = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(imageHtml));
            }
        });
        return this.images;
    }
}
```

The error has been thrown during execution of `ng serve --aot`. I've tried to google and to use service factory, but without success. I want to provide service in such way, because I want to have one instance of it per component. Have you any idea how to achive this?

Comment: Have you added the Service as a provider in the module?

Comment: @fredrik: she doesn't want to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing `Injectable` from the wrong path inside `QuestionImagesService`. Change the import to:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: You are genious